# execute gdb from bash loop quits immediately

Tags: bash, loops, gdb

I have a simple bash script that runs some program 3 times in a loop (/home/oren/Downloads/users.txt file has a single line)

```
#!/bin/bash
#######################
# Loop over all users #
#######################
while IFS='' read -r username
do
    for answer in {1..3};
    do
        ##############################################
        # Only perform check if both files exist ... #
        ##############################################
        if [ -f /home/oren/Downloads/someFile.txt ] && [ -f /home/oren/Downloads/anotherFile.txt ];
        then
            gdb --args /home/oren/Downloads/MMM/example PPP DDD 
        fi
    done
done < /home/oren/Downloads/users.txt
```

Here is /home/oren/Downloads/users.txt file:

```
cat /home/oren/Downloads/users.txt
```

And the answer is:

```
OrenIshShalom
```

When I **remove** the **gdb --args** prefix the **program works fine** (that is, it divides by zero like it should)
Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i=0;
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        i = (i+argc)/(argc-3);
    }
}
```

However when I add the gdb --args, gdb **quits immediately**:

```
...
(gdb) quit
```

What's going on here? Thanks!

EDIT:

When I remove the outer loop **gdb works fine** ... but I would very much prefer to **keep this loop** as everything in the script is built on it

Comment: How do you run the script? Is perhaps `stdin` closed when `gdb` is started?

Comment: I run it from terminal ... and gdb prints its "hello" message to that terminal ... it means  it's OK right?

Comment: A [mcve] please.

Comment: What does your SomeProgram do ? I try your script replacing "SomeProgram Input1 Input2" by "echo Input1" and gdb doesn't quit at startup.

Comment: @Emily E. when I try to make a minimal, complete and verifiable example everything works fine ... I thought that maybe it's because the program is in a different directory than the c files, but that's not it ...

Comment: I have found a complete, minimal and verifiable example and edited the question. It seems that the outer loop is causing some damage, even though there is only one user to iterate over ... probably the indirection < symbol ??

Comment: are you going to **manually** interact with the `gdb` session?

Comment: @pynexj, yes, when things go wrong I would like to debug the program, and eventually when it all works out, just comment out the gdb --args \ line ... and keep everything else unchanged ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole `while` loop (including `read` and `gdb`) would share the *stdin* which is `/home/oren/Downloads/users.txt` so your `gdb` would also consume data from `/home/oren/Downloads/users.txt`. `gdb` exits immediately because it quickly consumes all data and sees EOF.

See following example:

```
[STEP 109] # cat file
line 1
line 2
line 3
[STEP 110] # cat foo.sh
while read line; do
    gdb /bin/ls
done < file
[STEP 111] # bash foo.sh
GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
[...]
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /bin/ls...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) Undefined command: "line".  Try "help".
(gdb) Undefined command: "line".  Try "help".
(gdb) quit
[STEP 112] #
```

For your case you can load the file `/home/oren/Downloads/users.txt` to an array and go through it:

```
usernames=()
nusers=0
while IFS='' read -r username; do
    usernames[nusers++]=$username
done < /home/oren/Downloads/users.txt

for username in "${usernames[@]}"; do
    ...

    gdb ...

    ...
done
```

Comment: but is there anyway around this? maybe with some parentheses around something (?)